# Do I have to write the (R) and (TM) of e.g. "Intel Core i5" in an academic publication?

Tags: trademark

I'm finalising an academic publication (a written research paper that will be published at a conference and be available online), and I am mentioning the computer used to run the experiments:

> Intel Core i5-4460

Now I was wondering: Should I, or do I have to, put the trademark symbols in there as well? I.e.:

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460

(of course with the appropriate latex-symbols instead, i.e. the circle and in superscript).

Is there any requirement by law to do it? What would you advise, or what's the "best practice", if there's any, for similar circumstances?

I thought this was the most appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: This is up to the journal style in question, and the editor is likely to change your draft to reflect the house style. For what it's worth, in my recollection, the high quality journals will not use either symbol nor explicitly acknowledge the trademark in the text.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

A trade mark simply protects the company's exclusive right to use it to identify their goods and services. (R) means that the trade mark has been registered, TM means that, while not registered, the company is claiming a trade mark. Trade marks do not have to be registered to be enforceable.

You are certainly not infringing their trade mark by what you are doing and you are not laying claim to the trade mark, so there is no requirement to use the symbols.

Best practice *is* to use the symbols and identify who they belong to: "Intel and Core are trade marks of xyz".

Comment: I have a flavor of this question... What if the TM used in the title of a journal publication uses your Trademark to refer to something else that infringes your trademark? Is there a legal claim against the publisher, or only the entity that misrepresented my TM as being theirs? I have a similar question. I'm spoiled by the quickness of Stack Overflow exchange.  http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/do-i-have-a-trademark-case-for-an-academic-journal-using-my-tm-in-the-title-of-a

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you work for Intel.

"(R)" and "TM" are used by the holder of the trademark to indicate that it is a trademark. They are used methodically by trademark holders to ensure that there can never be a successful claim that the holder does not intend for the symbol to be a trademark by its own use of the symbol in a non-trademark context. You'll notice that nobody else puts (R) or TM after other people's trademarks.

Unless you work for Intel, you have no legal duty to protect Intel's trademarks. You should, however, state that "Intel" and "Core" are trademarks of Intel at the end of your paper.

Comment: I'm curious - `You should, however, state that "Intel" and "Core" are trademarks of Intel at the end of your paper.` This would be quite unusual in my field - nobody does this, I've never seen it in any academic publication from my field and surroundings. Also, space is usually very limited, so you wouldn't add a sentence that doesn't benefit your scientific content and is not absolutely necessary.